# Selenium Automation + chromedriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to automate a web application wherein clicking a link downloads a PDF file. The default behavior of chromedriver should open a pop-up window for confirmation. I am facing issue with the same, In my case the file is directly downloading without prompting.(I need to pop up to change the file name)

Comment: can you post some code, and phrase a question

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that there is no easy way to make Selenium download files. Browsers use native dialogs which cannot be controlled by JavaScript.

Why are you downloading a file in the first place?

Check out [this](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/07/file-downloads-with-selenium-mission-impossible/) for more detail.

Comment: Excellent answer. People forget this is just HTTP, and that there's a whole world of tried-and-tested tools for testing downloads that are quicker and more reliable than trying to trick a web browser.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually want to use window automation using AutoIT to save the file to a particular location but in my default chrome settings the option to save a file to a particular location is unchecked due to which I don't get a pop up wheein I can change the path to save the file.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can make a custom profile

Answer (score 0):

This can be set via settings option,

refer the below link https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95574